# ftp client on linux '500 '': command not understood. '

Tags: linux, ftp, berkeley-sockets

i try to make simple ftp client to get list of files on bsd sockets. Here it is:

```
connectTo(int client_socket, 
              struct sockaddr_in* addr,
              char* ipv4Address,
              char* user,
              char* password,
              char* response) // buffer wchich store responses
{
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socket < 0)
    {
        printf("Can not create socket");
        return 2;
    }

    addr->sin_family = AF_INET; // address family - internet socket
    addr->sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER);
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipv4Address);
    if(connect(client_socket,(struct sockaddr*)addr,sizeof(*addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Can not connect!\n");
        return 3;
    }

    int size_read = recv(client_socket, response, BUF_SIZE, 0);

        printf("size_read = %d\n",size_read);
        response[size_read] = '\0'; // for not printing rubbish
        printf("%s\n",response);

    printf("sending username\n");
    char *username = strdup("USER trenkinan\r\n");
    send(client_socket,username,strlen(username)+1,0);


    size_read = recv(client_socket, response, BUF_SIZE, 0);

   //     printf("size_read = %d\n",size_read);
        response[size_read] = '\0'; // for not printing rubbish
        printf("%s",response);
    if(strstr(response,"331"))
    {
        //printf("sending password\n");
        char *passwd = strdup("PASS test\r\n");

       // printf("passwd string: %s",passwd);
        int sent = send(client_socket,passwd,strlen(passwd)+1,0);
        size_read = recv(client_socket, response, BUF_SIZE, 0);
        response[size_read] = '\0'; // for not printing rubbish
        printf("%s",response);

        //printf("sent bytes: %d\n", sent); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I use ftp server from debian repository(ftpd) on my work station. I try to execute this code and when i send password server answer that 500 '': command not understood. 
  I use wireshark to see what happens and all packages from my program looks fine, i use ftp command(lightweight ftp client on linux) to connect and it works but packages from that client looks the same as from my own client. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, i found a bug: strlen(username) instead of strlen(username)+1. I hope it will help to someone.

Comment: oh man had a similar issue and ur question helped me to locate my bug =)